# Analyze rule body in different rule

Tags: reflection, prolog

I need to be able to access the body of a rule in a different rule. For example, in the following, I want to be able to use the facts of `rule` in `myRule` when I call `myRule(rule)`.

```
rule :-
    fact1(...),
    fact2(...),
    fact3(...).


myRule(RuleName) :-
    RuleName :- (F1, F2, F3),
    write(F1).
```

Obviously the above code does not work, and I have no idea of how to go about this, so I am asking for tips or anything to get me going in the right direction.

Please note that I am very new to Prolog and to logic programming in general. I'm having a hard time finding answers since I am not sure what exactly to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `clause(Head, Body)` allows you to inspect rules.  Thus, `clause(rule, (F1,F2,F3))` should succeed, binding `F1`, etc.  Note that the standard demands the predicate to inspect to be declared *dynamic*,  SWI-Prolog doesn't enforce that.

Comment: It works perfectly, now I just need to find how to make it work for a variable amount of rules in the body. Thank very much

Comment: Use `clause(rule, Body)`.  Body is unified with the term (F1,F2,F3,...), a nested term of `','(First, Rest)`.  I'll leave processing this term to you.

Comment: I managed it with something of the sorts: `look_at_tuple((X, Y)) :- look_at_tuple(Y).` with extra steps of course.